# powershell - new-aduser skip empty cells CSV - attributes with -

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I really really need your help. I got a task to create/import users from csv to AD.

But I have two problems

1. not all the user have all the attributes filled = there are empty "cells" in CSV
2. Two custom attributes contains dash - and PSH is returning error that this is not allowed.

I tried to search, there are some solutions but I am not sure how to implement it to my file (| ForEach-Object {$CSV = $_ ?????. Cant make it work.

Here is what I have so far

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$ScriptDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$log = "$ScriptDir\Error-Import.log"
$log1 = "$ScriptDir\Success-Import.log" 
$date = Get-Date
$inputFile = Import-CSV $ScriptDir\allusers.csv 

Function cUser 
{ 

"ERROR LOG from (" + $date + ")      :" | Out-File $log -Append 
"————————————————-" | Out-File $log -Append
"Following accounts has been successfully created (" + $date + ")      :" | Out-File $log1 -        Append 
"————————————————-" | Out-File $log1 -Append  
foreach($line in $inputFile) 
{ 
$sam = $line.samaccoutnname

#check if user already exists

$exists = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$sam)" 
if (!$exists) 
{ 
# when does not exists - load data from CSV and set as variable
$gn = $line.givenName
$sn = $line.sn
$title = $line.title
$stAd=$line.streetAddress
$upn = $line.sAMAccountName + "`@targetrange.local"
$city=$line.l
$st=$line.st
$postc=$line.postalCode
$ehrd=$line.award-hireDate
$comp=$line.company
$dvs=$line.division
$edvs=$line.award-subdivision
$dept=$line.department
$st=$line.street
$tarA=$line.targetAddress
$dn=$line.displayName
$ext2=$line.extensionAttribute2
$ext4=$line.extensionAttribute4
$ext5=$line.extensionAttribute5
$alias = $line.sAMAccountName
$cn=$line.cn
$hdir=$line.unixHomeDirectory
$desc=$line.description
$pat = $line.OU
$pwd = $line.pass
$spass =ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $pwd
$aexp=$line.accountExpires
$Expconv=(Get-Date $aexp ).ToFileTime()

New-ADUser -SamAccountName $alias -UserPrincipalName $upn -GivenName $gn -Surname $sn -title $title -StreetAddress $stAd -l $city -State $st -PostalCode $postc -award-hireDate $ehrd -Company $comp -Division $dvs -award-subdivision $edvs -Department $dept -street $st -targetAddress $tarA -extensionAttribute2 $ext2 -extensionAttribute4 $ext4 -extensionAttribute5 $ext5 -DisplayName $dn -Name $cn -unixHomeDirectory $hdir -Description $Desc -path $pat -AccountExpirationDate $Expconv -AccountPassword $spass -PassThru | Enable-ADAccount 

$exists1 = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$sam)" 
if ($exists1) 
{ 

     "User successfully created : " + $sam | Out-File $log1 -Append 

} 
Else 
    { 
    "SKIPPED – MISSING OR INCORRECT VALUES : " + $sam | Out-File $log -Append 
    } 


} 
# if user already exists - skip and write to logfile 
Else 
    { 
    "SKIPPED – ALREADY EXISTS OR DUPLICATE ALIAS : " + $sam | Out-File $log -Append 
    } 
} 
"————————————————-" + "`n" | Out-File $log -Append 
} 
createUsers
  # finito
  }
```

If you can help, it would save my life :-) How to skip empty cells??? And to make attributes with - working - apostrophe is enough? 'award-hiredate' ?

Comment: There is a typo around line 20 ish `$sam = $line.samaccoutnname` that could be contributing to the script failing.

Comment: So could _ANY_ cell be empty and you would have to account for it. If there was an empty cell in a row you would ignore it and not make a user based on it?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you wanted to skip empty cells. I am not sure how far you wanted to take that but here is something I think does the trick.  You have the line.

```
$inputFile = Import-CSV $ScriptDir\allusers.csv
```

I would propose it gets updated as follows

```
$inputFile = Import-CSV $ScriptDir\allusers.csv |  Where-Object{$_.psobject.properties.value -notcontains ""}
```

What this will do is break each entry into an array of its values. If any of the values are empty or `""` then they will not be matched into the `$inputFile`.

```
Count                         EventID                       EventType                    
-----                         -------                       ---------                    
14                                                          Information                  
2                             7040                          Information                  
2                             0                                                          
1                             8224                          Information
```

The above data was put into the filter and the output was

```
Count                         EventID                       EventType                    
-----                         -------                       ---------                    
2                             7040                          Information                  
1                             8224                          Information
```

As you can see the lines with empty data are filtered out and the data structure is still preserved.

**The Hyphen**

As for the hyphen `-` issue I'm assuming the error you are getting is `Unexpected token '-Type' in expression or statement.` Guessing it is trying to treat the `-hireData` in `$line.award-hireDate`. What you are trying to do is the best in this case. Just use quotes around the parameter name. You would do the same if the parameter had a space in it.

```
$line."award-hireDate"
$line."award hireDate"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Thanks to you I understand now how it works. I splitted script to two separate functions, because I need ALL users to be created but only NOT EMPTY attributes to be set. And your update did a trick! I was fighting with it for days! THANKS THANKS THANKS!

Comment: That is good to hear. I'm glad it helped. Please show your appreciation by marking this as the accepted answer. Hope to see you again on SO.